# Where do I turn route highlighting on / off in Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, user-interface, navigation

How can I show / hide the blue line representing the current route in Google Maps route planning and navigation screens? Essentially I want to toggle between the two views below:

[image]
[image]

Background: I somehow managed to switch route highlighting off and now I want it back. It doesn't seem to be a bug in Google Maps, at least a phone restart doesn't restore the highlighting. I know I can just wipe Google Maps user data, but I prefer to learn how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route highlighting reappeared when my phone went back online, so apparently it's not something one can configure. Note that simply being offline is not enough to make the highlighting disappear: I have used Google Maps with offline maps many times, and it was never disabled before.